# What is wrong with this code??? it says the error Identifier expected

Tags: c#

```
    public static Dictionary<uint, Items.GroundItem> ItemFilter(Client C, Dictionary<uint, Items.GroundItem> oggettiInteri)
    {
        Dictionary<uint, string> Filtr = new Dictionary<uint, string>();
        Dictionary<uint, Items.GroundItem> Rientro = new Dictionary<uint, Items.GroundItem>();

        if (C.Looting)
            Filtr = Program.RareItem; //Program doesnt contain defenition for Rare item
        else if (C.LootMoney)
        {
            Filtr.Add(1090020, "Money");
            Filtr.Add(1091000, "Money");
            Filtr.Add(1091010, "Money");
            Filtr.Add(1091020, "Money");
        }    
    }
```

Comment: This `Program.;` will not work. Are you missing a property here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help get the most out of this site, please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Also please don't completely change the question after posting it. Editing is for adding clarifications to your existing question, not to ask a different question. If after getting the answer to a question you have a new question, then post it as a completely new question. Also your tags are not appropriate. I'd suggest using just the `c#` here, not the `microsoft` or `visual` tags.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial error was because this line was incomplete.

```
Filtr = Program.;
```

It looks like you didn't finish writing that line, or else you accidentally deleted some of the code that was there.

---

The new error is because the class Program that you have defined doesn't contain any definition for `RareItem` or else you don't have access to it.

You need to define find the definition of the class Program, add a RareItem property, and set it to some value somewhere:

```
class Program
{
    public static Item RareItem { get; }

    static void Main()
    {
        RareItem = new Item(); // TODO: Finish this.
    }

    ...
}
```

By the way, public static global data is generally not a good idea. You might want to try to find a different design.

---

I'd also recommend using curly braces and consistent indentation to make it more clear what is going on:

```
if (C.Looting)
{
    Filtr = Program.RareItem;
}

while (C.LootMoney)
{
    Filtr.Add(1090020, "Money");
    Filtr.Add(1091000, "Money");
    Filtr.Add(1091010, "Money");
    Filtr.Add(1091020, "Money");
}
```

Be careful that the `while` loop doesn't give you an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
Filtr = Program.;
```

This is wrong, you'll need something after the dot.

Answer (score 0):

You are assignment statement is incomplete.

```
if(C.Looting)
{
  Filtr = Program.  // incomplete
}
```

In Program class if you have defined another static variable of type Dictionary let's say LocalFilter; then you can assign it to Filtr;

```
if(C.Looting)
{
  Filtr = Program.LocalFilter;
}
```